# strassen algorithm for any input

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix-multiplication

How can we change the [Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) so that it works for a matrix of any size (for example for n=5)?

Comment: If I were you, I'd add a reference to what Strassen algorithm is to spare us some googling :)

Comment: The only thing I could think of was Boost (uBlas); However, according to [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/ublas/index.php?title=Main_Page) Strassen's is still on the TODO list

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is pad the matrices with rows and columns of 0s untill they are square matrices whose size is a power of 2. Or to put it another way:

Place the matrices to be multiplied in the upper left corners of two 2^n x 2^n matrices. Set all the unused elements to 0. Then just run the algorithm, and the result you want will be in the upper left corner of the result matrix.

Comment: Uh is the resulting algorithm then slower than the standard multiplication algorithm?

Comment: No, it would still be faster for large matrices. Say N -  the size - is between 2^(n-1) and 2^n. Then, the simple version would use O(N^3) operations, which is at least O(2^(3n - 3)). The Strassen is around O(N^2.8) i.e. O(2^(2.8n)). Usually 2^(3n - 3) tends to be larger than 2^(2.8n) :)